# Convert IEnumerable<dynamic> to JsonArray

Tags: c#, linq

I am selecting an `IEnumerable<dynamic>` from the database using Rob Conery's Massive framework. The structure comes back in a flat format Poco C#. I need to transform the data and output it to a Json array (format show at bottom).

I thought I could do the transform using linq (my unsuccessful effort is shown below):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Json;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

....
    IEnumerable<dynamic> list = _repository.All("", "", 0).ToList();

    JsonArray returnValue = from item in list
                            select new JsonObject()
                                       {
                                               Name = item.Test,
                                               Data = new dyamic(){...}...
                                       };
```

Here is the Json I am trying to generate:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Data Title",
        "data": [
            {
                "column1 name": "the value",
                "column2 name": "the value",
                "column3 name": "",
                "column4 name": "the value"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Data Title",
        "data": [
            {
                "column1 name": "the value",
                "column2 name": "the value",
                "column3 name": "the value",
                "column4 name": "the value"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: First, why are you using `dynamic` in this situation?  Presumably `_repository` is typed?  Second, why aren't you using a serializer such as `JavaScriptSerializer` or JSON.net?  Third, `JsonValue` is abstract, so you cannot instantiate it.

Comment: Have you investigated the DataContractJsonSerializer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx?

Comment: Have you taken a look at JayRock for .Net? Seems quite good. I think you can parse objects up as JsonObjects.

Comment: @kirk The Massive Micro ORM returns dynamic objects see https://github.com/robconery/massive. The dynamic objects are not strongly typed. JsonValue was incorrect it should have been a JsonObject.

Comment: @phil DataContractJsonSerialization looks like it is for strongly typed objects, how could I do something similar with dynamic objects?

Comment: @Burt, thanks for clarifying.  Now -- are you getting any errors?  If so, what are they?

Comment: @Kirk - I get 'System.Json.JsonObject' does not contain a definition for 'Name' ..., same for Data when trying to create the new JsonObject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() {1 , 2};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                  list.Select(x => new{
                      id = x.ToString(),
                      title = "title " + x.ToString(),
                      data = Enumerable.Range(3,2).Select(i=> new {column1=i,column2=i*i})
                    })
                  , Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
                );
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "title 1",
    "data": [
      {
        "column1": 3,
        "column2": 9
      },
      {
        "column1": 4,
        "column2": 16
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "title 2",
    "data": [
      {
        "column1": 3,
        "column2": 9
      },
      {
        "column1": 4,
        "column2": 16
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you, was a bit worried my question didn't make any sense there :)

Answer (score 0):

OK here is what I ended up with it all looks hunky dory:

```
   [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/tools/data/get?tool={tool}&filters={filters}")]
    public JsonArray GetData(string tool, string[,] filters)
    {
        IEnumerable<dynamic> list = _repository.All("", "", 0).ToList();


        IEnumerable<JsonObject> jsonList = from item in list
                                select new JsonObject()
                                           {
                                               new KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue>("Id", item.Id),
                                               new KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue>("Name", item.Title),
                                               new KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue>("Data", new JsonObject()
                                                                                               {
                                                                                                    new KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue>("Product", item.Product),
                                                                                                    new KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue>("Suite", item.Suite),
                                                                                                    new KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue>("Package", item.Package),
                                                                                                    new KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue>("Description", item.Description)
                                                                                               })

                                           };

        JsonArray returnValue = new JsonArray(jsonList);

        return returnValue;
    }
```